# Looking for a right way to inject Vue data in axios interceptor

Tags: vuejs3, inject

I have a Vue 3 plugin for popup messages. This plugin extract it methods with use function and looks like

```
export function usePopup () {
  const { addModal, addMessage, addToast } = inject(PopupInjectionKey) as PopupMethods;

  return { addModal, addMessage, addToast };
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement global axios interceptor and I want to use my modal message to show errors from requests.

So I created method:

```
export function registerInterceptorGeneric () {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    if (error?.response) {
      const { status, data, headers } = error.response;
      const { addMessage } = usePopup();
      switch (status) {
        case 409:
          addMessage(data.message, MessageType.Info);
        break;
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

I call this method from **main.ts**, but unfortunately, usePopup is obviously out of context. So my question is - how i can pass Context to this function? Or maybe I should call this function from App.ts with addMessage as argument? I'm new to Vue, so, what's the right way to do such things?

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same problem